# Problems transferring Flash project from Mac to Windows

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

I have a .fla on my Mac that I created in Flash cs5. I saved it as a cs4 file and sent it to a friend who has a Windows machine.

I have a symbol linked to an AS class which has symbols inside of it which have instance names. The constructor of the class refers to these instance names. When I compile, everything works as expected. When my friend compiles, he gets compiler errors telling him that the instances mentioned above are undefined.

I'm at a complete loss. Any ideas why this is happening?

Things we've tried:

- Checked to make sure that we had the same source path
- Made sure that the symbol in the Flash IDE has the correct linkage
- Tried compiling the .fla with cs4 on my machine. It works, which is what makes me think it's a Mac/Windows issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to publish settings -> flash -> [settings button next to "as3] - the same place you go to set your classpath. There is a checkbox there that says declare stage instances - it sounds like its unchecked on the cs4 windows version... it should be checked if you don't want to have to write things like :

```
public var myClip:MovieClip;
```

for every instance that you've placed using the flash ide.